# PII network sample, want to authorize another participant

Tags: hyperledger-composer

so I am using the pii sample network. And originally, the network has only one participant which is the Member, and the member authorizes or revokes access of his information to other members.

However, I want to change that and add a new participant, say 'Doctor', and the member can authorize or revoke access the Doctor participant.

The problem is that when I added a new Doctor participant and want to authorize it, the transaction does not search in the Doctor Participant, but in the Member participant.

So, can anyone help me out in pointing what should I change? is it the  logic, or the definition? or what?

pii.cto

```
namespace org.acme.pii

concept Address {
  o String street
  o String house
  o String city
  o String county
  o String country
  o String zip
}

participant Member identified by email {
  o String email
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o DateTime dob optional
  o Address address optional
  o String[] authorized optional
}

participant Doctor identified by email {
  o String email
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o DateTime dob optional
  o Address address optional
  o String[] authorized optional
}

abstract transaction MemberTransaction {
  o String memberId
}

abstract transaction DoctorTransaction {
  o String memberId
}

transaction AuthorizeAccess extends MemberTransaction {
}

transaction RevokeAccess extends MemberTransaction {
}

event MemberEvent {
  o MemberTransaction memberTransaction
}
```

Logic.js

```
async function authorizeAccess(authorize) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

    const me = getCurrentParticipant();
    console.log('**** AUTH: ' + me.getIdentifier() + ' granting access to ' + authorize.memberId );

    if(!me) {
        throw new Error('A participant/certificate mapping does not exist.');
    }

    // if the member is not already authorized, we authorize them
    let index = -1;

    if(!me.authorized) {
        me.authorized = [];
    }
    else {
        index = me.authorized.indexOf(authorize.memberId);
    }

    if(index < 0) {
        me.authorized.push(authorize.memberId);

        // emit an event
        const event = getFactory().newEvent('org.acme.pii', 'MemberEvent');
        event.memberTransaction = authorize;
        emit(event);

        // persist the state of the member
        const memberRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.pii.Member');
        await memberRegistry.update(me);
    }
}

/**
 * A Member revokes access to their record from another Member.
 * @param {org.acme.pii.RevokeAccess} revoke - the RevokeAccess to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
async function revokeAccess(revoke) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

    const me = getCurrentParticipant();
    console.log('**** REVOKE: ' + me.getIdentifier() + ' revoking access to ' + revoke.memberId );

    if(!me) {
        throw new Error('A participant/certificate mapping does not exist.');
    }

    // if the member is authorized, we remove them
    const index = me.authorized ? me.authorized.indexOf(revoke.memberId) : -1;

    if(index>-1) {
        me.authorized.splice(index, 1);

        // emit an event
        const event = getFactory().newEvent('org.acme.pii', 'MemberEvent');
        event.memberTransaction = revoke;
        emit(event);

        // persist the state of the member
        const memberRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.pii.Member');
        await memberRegistry.update(me);
    }
}
```

permissions.acl

```
rule AuthorizeAccessTransaction {
    description: "Allow all participants to submit AuthorizeAccess transactions"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: CREATE
    resource: "org.acme.pii.AuthorizeAccess"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule RevokeAccessTransaction {
    description: "Allow all participants to submit RevokeAccess transactions"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: CREATE
    resource: "org.acme.pii.RevokeAccess"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule OwnRecordFullAccess {
    description: "Allow all participants full access to their own record"
    participant(p): "org.acme.pii.Member"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "org.acme.pii.Member"
    condition: (r.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

rule DoctorAccess {
    description: "Allow all participants full access to their own record"
    participant(p): "org.acme.pii.Doctor"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "org.acme.pii.Doctor"
    condition: (r.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

rule ForeignRecordConditionalAccess {
    description: "Allow participants access to other people's records if granted"
    participant(p): "org.acme.pii.Member"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "org.acme.pii.Member"
    condition: (r.authorized && r.authorized.indexOf(p.getIdentifier()) > -1)
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
    description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

queries.qry

```
query selectMembers {
  description: "Select all members"
  statement:
      SELECT org.acme.pii.Member
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. 
In the acl file, I just needed it to change

```
rule ForeignRecordConditionalAccess {
    description: "Allow participants access to other people's records if granted"
    participant(p): "org.acme.pii.Doctor"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "org.acme.pii.Member"
    condition: (r.authorized && r.authorized.indexOf(p.getIdentifier()) > -1)
    action: ALLOW
}
```